# Tensor Index Manipulation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, metric-tensor, differentiation, matrix-elements

I am trying to study General Relativity and I thought about starting with some index gymnastics. I found a worksheet online and I am stuck with a simple problem. I have to prove that

$$\partial_{\mu} g^{\nu\rho} = -g^{\nu\kappa}g^{\rho\lambda}\partial_{\mu}g_{\lambda\kappa}$$

available info is that all Greek letters are from 0 to 3.

Also, do you know any resources with solved problems like that I can work on?

Answer (score 4):

Let $A$ be any matrix and $A^{-1}$ its inverse, so $AA^{-1}=I$. Then
$$
0 =dI = d(A^{-1})A+ A^{-1}dA
$$
Thus, on multiplying by $A^{-1}$ on the right we have
$$
d (A^{-1})= -A^{-1} (dA) A^{-1}
$$
Now recall that if $g_{\mu\nu}$ is the metric regarded as a matrix, then $g^{\mu\nu}$ is its inverse: $g_{\mu\nu}g^{\nu\lambda}= \delta^\lambda_\mu$.